# Is there a reason/setting that would prevent a Coldfusion server from running recursive functions

Tags: coldfusion, recursion, coldfusion-9, recursive-query

I am using Hostek.com, shared hosting, and can't seem to get a recursive function to run.

Comment: Try running a recursive function

Comment: don't forget to Var scope your local variable.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't get (it) to run"? An error, wrong results, ...? You might also want to post your code.

Answer (score 3):

No. There is no such setting